# Access Denied when downloading via Signed URLs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using an IAM role to access S3 from my EC2 instance. But in my application, I create a signed URL for downloading the files. However, when the user tries to download the files, it is showing **access denied** errors.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

//key=file path
var params = {Bucket: bucket, Key: prefix+'/'+key, Expires: 240}
var url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params)
console.log(req.cookies.s, 'got', url) // expires in 60 seconds
res.redirect(url)
```

Comment: Try to combine with `AWS S3 Bucket Policy` to public your s3 objects. Ref: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html

Comment: Can you show some code?  The signed URL is the correct way to handle this.  I would strongly advise against opening up your bucket to the public unless you know for sure that's what you want.

Comment: uploaded files must be set to public. Otherwise your app should have some acl to set uploaded file to public

Comment: @Ayoub I don't want to open the data publicly.

Answer (score 7):

The fact that you are providing Signed URLs and they result in an `Access Denied` error says that **the Signed URL is not valid**.

Some potential reasons:

- The Signed URL was **incorrectly constructed** (you didn't show us your code, so we can't determine this)
- The credentials used to generate the Signed URL does not have **permission to access the objects** (a Signed URL is a way to authorise temporary, limited usage of credentials, but the underlying credentials must have access to the resource)
- The **time period for the Signed URL expired** (but this would result in a different error message)
- The **object does not exist** (which is quite likely, since `Access Denied` suggests this, rather than displaying an error related to the Signed URL)

Comment: Whenever I use keys in my application the download process seems perfect. after removing commenting keys with roles, listing seems perfect but download not working. there is no change in code.

Comment: This "The credentials used to generate the Signed URL does not have permission to access the objects (a Signed URL is a way to authorise temporary, limited usage of credentials, but the underlying credentials must have access to the resource)" is what happened in my case. Makes sense in hindsight, but missed this. The creator of the signed url did not have permissions to read the object to begin with ^^'

Comment: just for the sake of explicitness, point (2) here means that the lambda writing the file needs to have GetObject permissions as well, otherwise you can imagine there's a security flaw here.... so its easy to fall here - that lambda has write permissions to create a signed url that is useless. Funnily enough - granting read permissions to the lambda would make all pre signed urls created previously magically work.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for @john 's answer to point out the main issue with the `Access Denied`is that the signed URL is not valid.

I want to add another thing that helps sort this issue out. **Even you don't have correct credentials to the bucket, you will still be able to generate the signed URL**!

That's where it got me stuck, as I didn't think my credentials were not correct as I generated the URL successfully.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was other, so maybe I can help someone.

What I was lacking was the Permissions for the Lambda to use the S3 Bucket. I added this to the template **where the LambdaFunction is defined**:

```
Properties:
  Policies:
    - AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
    - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
    - S3CrudPolicy:
        BucketName: !Ref MyS3Bucket
```

(**the last 2 lines are the important!** I just put all the policies for reference...)